# Qt Scanning Wi-Fi with QT6

Tags: qt, wifi, qt6

QNetworkAccessManager is removed in QT6. Has anybody an idea on how to get available SSIDs with QT6 / without QNetworkAccessManager / QNetworkconfiguration?

Comment: You may use `wpa_supplicant` https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/

Answer (score 0):

@Flow Are you sure? I've just checked 6.1 and 6.2 (Dev), but QNetworkAccessManager is still part of Qt. See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html
Could you maybe have omitted QNetwork via flags for the build (if self-built)?

Answer (score 0):

you are right. I had an typo: QNetworkConfigurationManager and QNetworkConfiguration is depreated in QT6.

Best regards,
Florian